# RGB cube of an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rgb, cube

I'm trying to create a RGB cube of a image with matplotlib in python. I have a python list with the RGB of all the pixels in format `[(2,152,255),(0,0,0)...]`. I plot all the points with scatter function, but i don't know how to plot each RGB point with it's respective RGB colour.

I've tried doing something like this `ax.scatter(paleta[0],paleta[1],paleta[2],c = RGBlist)`, but the function expect a RGBa value...

I expect somthig like this:

[image]

**CODE :**

`paleta=zip(*RGBlist)        
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(paleta[0],paleta[1],paleta[2])
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_title('grid on')
plt.savefig('Images\\RGBcube.png')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try scaling your RGB values to the range [0,1]:

`ax.scatter(paleta[0],paleta[1],paleta[2], c=[(r[0] / 255., r[1] / 255., r[2] / 255.) for r in RGBlist])`

This works in the following example:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

RGBlist = [(random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)) for i in range(100)]
paleta=zip(*RGBlist)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(paleta[0],paleta[1],paleta[2], c=[(r[0] / 255., r[1] / 255., r[2] / 255.) for r in RGBlist])
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_title('grid on')
plt.savefig('blah.png')
```

Giving the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set `color` attribute in [`scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) function:

> color - matplotlib color arg or sequence of rgba tuples